# Restricting photo size for attributes displayed in qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have created field for objects in a layer that allow me to input links that will display a photo on mouse-over for that object in a webmap made with the qgis2web plugin for QGIS v3.2.

How do I restrict the image size to some preset boundary? Currently, each photo is displayed at full extent. I don't want to resize the image to explicit dimensions, because some are oriented vertically, while others are oriented horizontally. I would like to preserve the original aspect ratio of the photos, while reducing their overall size.

Added 9/24/18: I am exporting as OpenLayers.

Comment: Can you tell us whether you are exporting your webmap in OpenLayers or Leaflet format (you choose this in the qgis2web dialog)? The answer will be different for each.

Comment: Exporting in OpenLayers. I added that to my question. Thank you @TomChadwin

Comment: please give me code and instructions how to do the same for leaflet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your exported map code, and open the file `./resources/qgis2web.css` in a text editor. Add the following to the end of the file:

```
#popup-content img {max-width: 200px;}
```

Change `200px` to the width you want. This won't enlarge images narrower than the stated `max-width`, but if all your images are larger, this could work for you.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted and worked perfectly.

Comment: Regards, I have the same problem, I have seen your answer and Im doing the step of copy *#popup-content img {max-width: 200px;}* to qgis2web.css but the results is equal [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYzvT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYzvT.jpg)