# Adjust image in qgis2web to pop up

Tags: qgis, popup

When exporting a webmap using qgis2web, the images I want to display are way to big and it makes very difficult to navigate through the map. Is there any way I can make them smaller and fit it to the pop up?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could be help:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296778/restricting-photo-size-for-attributes-displayed-in-qgis2web
Or you could resize your images for the popup: for example width: 300px.

Comment: I have already read this article you mention but it didnt realle help me because I didnt know where and how i should write the code he mentioned. Could you either clarify me that or show me where can i resize my images for the pop up? Thanks

Comment: I guess the proposal to resize you images referred to resize them outside of QGIS in a regular image processing software like GIMP, Affinity Photo or Photoshop and than use this reduced files in your project. If you don't want to show your pictures in the full resolution, it makes no sense to have them embedded with that degree of detail, just to resize them on the map canvas: waste of resources

Comment: This solution could be great if the amount of images were small .. I would rather prefer to touch the code somehow into the html file (if possible) to make them smaller and able to fit in the pop up.. But 1. I dont know if this is possible and 2. I dont how

Comment: With the free software photoscape http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/download.php you can change the size of many images at once. And you can have the same or new file names. With the function batch processing for different image formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, you can add a simple css rule to determine max width for the images.
The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296778/restricting-photo-size-for-attributes-displayed-in-qgis2web) won't work for you anymore since leaflet has changed the name of the popup content class.
There is also the problem where qgis2web uses a table inside its popups.

what you need to do, is open the `index.html` file and edit the ` tag.

instead of just:

```
<style>
  #map {
            width: 894px;
            height: 813px;
        }
</style>
```

add :

```
<style>
#map {
     width: 894px;
     height: 813px;
   }
 .leaflet-popup-content > table img {
    width: 300px;
   }
 .leaflet-popup-content > img { /*for other leaflet maps you can add rule as well*/
    width: 300px;
   }
</style>
```

you can change the number of pixels to match how you want you images to look.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot #Dror Bogin, this code and your explanation has solved my problem perfectly. Thumbs up!